# What package do I need to isntall on CentOS 5 to get system-config-network X11 GUI?

Tags: linux, networking, configuration, packages, centos5

The title says it all really.

What package do I need to get via yum on CentOS 5 to be able to run the X11 version of system-config-network?

ATM I only have the tui version which is horrific.

Thanks,

Bart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install system-config-network it should pull all of the dependencies for X11.

Comment: I have system-config-network, but when I SSH in with -X and launch it it does not come up as the GUI like it does on all the other CentOS 5 machines I use. Could it just be as simple as installing X11 with something as simple as "yum install x11" and then the GUI for system-config-network will magically appear?

Comment: Do you have the XAuth package installed?  X forwarding requires this on Cent.  Make sure you have forwarding working with something like xclock or xterm first and then try system-config-network.

Comment: turns out that although I had a binary called system-config-network, I did not actually have the package system-config-network installed. I had system-config-network-tui installed, and it creates a binary system-config-network which it then points at itself. A tad confusing, but ultimately my boneheadedness caused it all!